# What happens when a server runs out of space?

Tags: linux

And by "runs out" I mean totally, including space reserved for root. Can I still log in? Can I spawn processes? Can I delete a big file if I know its location? Can I `find` or `ncdu` big files or directories?

Comment: You might have trouble logging in, "stuff" will fail in interesting ways but when you can login all commands that you need to find the cause and attempt to remedy a full root partition should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you still login?

- locally, yes, though problems may occur with your shell (bash auto-completion won't work, for instance).
- through ssh, it may work but in my experience it generally doesn't.

Can you spawn processes?

- Generally speaking, yes. However starting up services may fail (once again, because they would fail to create locks, write to logs, etc).

Can you delete files?

- Sure. Auto completion may not work, but generic shell commands work fine, including `find` (for `ncdu` I don't know, it may use temporary files and require at least some space).

Comment: Neither OpenSSH nor dropbear need to "create locks." What resource would they even be locking? For more information, `man sshd sshd_config |grep -w lock`. PAM can impose arbitrary requirements but by default it doesn't need a writeable filesystem either. SSH login will work.  PTY creation will fail if /dev lives on a disk; on systems that create them on demand and/or have no spares, you'll be limited to `ssh host command` and `ssh -T host`

Comment: @OhMyGoodness from my experience, it happened that ssh login failed on me because of a full root filesystem. It may not be a general rule, but it's common enough to be at least mentioned.

Comment: "It will generally fail" ... "It may not be a general rule"